# Git: how to compare to changesets without comitting them?

Tags: git

Given we have code generation tool that updates the files in our working dir. We run the tool with 2 different parameters and we want to understand which difference it brings. Is it possible to do it with GIT somehow?

Comment: Why not just commit, then `git reset` to eliminate the commit?

Comment: With TortoiseGit you can use _Diff later_ to compare any two local files. Probabily there is something like this in native Git.

Comment: Also there are plenty other ways to compare two files without Git. Notepad++ Compare plugin for instance.

Comment: ...or just plain diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that has worked well for me is do to something like:

```
# Make some change
git diff > first-try.patch

# Make a different change
git diff > second-try.patch

interdiff first-try.patch second-try.patch
```

The interdiff shows you a diff of diffs, which is useful.  You typically need patchutils installed on your Linux machine to get interdiff.

The other choice would be:

```
# Make some change
git commit -m "first try"
# Make note of the commit id... call it COMMIT1

# Restore your tree
git reset --hard HEAD^
# Make the second change
git commit -m "second try"

git diff COMMIT1 HEAD

# Go back to the original starting point.
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

I like this idea less, since you can screw things up if you make a mistake.  But it's also easier in other ways (doesn't require interdiff, for instance).  Note: you might think you can reference COMMIT1 since you back-pedaled, but that's not true.  Git will leave the object around and clean it up later, as long as it's not being used after a certain period of time.